# Filament Group Ipod Menu no show

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

The original example is here http://www.filamentgroup.com/examples/menus/ipod.php what I would like to achieve is to have the ipod style menu with breadcrumb (2nd one down) on the page without having to click the link to reveal the menu. This doesnt seem to be a CSS issue so must be jquery related, and triggers the menu on the click from the link, and try as I might I havent figured it out yet, anyone else been in the same situation and solved it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://wijmo.com/demo/explore/#menu|overview This iPod menu solves the issue, but you do of course need to be using Wijmo. Hope this helps anyone with the same issue.